# Looking for a bassoon piece

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I have this bassoon piece in my head and I cannot work out what it is.
It is for solo bassoon with piano accompaniment in D minor. The bassoon melody starts in 4/4 like so
[image]

Later there is a section in D flat major.
I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what this piece is called and who wrote it.

Edit: Myself playing the part I remember:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_J72OXGx6xSZkE0UF9CbVBKLVk/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: The harmonies suggest early 20th Century - perhaps [Hindemith Bassoon sonata](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIzIE1IcBng&t=3m17s) ??  not a piece I know well, but the third movement looks likely. And it looks like there is a section in Db major, around t=4m21s

Comment: Not it unfortunately, but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the *Solo de Concert* by Gabriel Pierné (1863-1937), op. 35, cf. [Youtube recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEwhnAQfvS0), right the start of the bassoon part, sheet music is available at [IMSLP](http://imslp.org/wiki/Solo_de_concert,_Op.35_(Piern%C3%A9,_Gabriel)).